# Derandomize MAX-CUT problem using $\log n$ bits

Tags: randomness, max-cut

Consider the MAX-CUT problem. We can flip $n$ coins to generate a random cut, and  by linearity of expectation we get that with "good probability" our cut we'll be bigger then $\frac{n}{2}$.

Using pseudo random generators (XOR for example) we can generate $n$ pairwise  independent bits from $\log n$ random bits. Using that approach, we can de-randomize the MAX-CUT problem with polynomial complexity.

With that algorithm, we are only checking $n$ possible cuts, where there are total of $2^n$. Is it promised that a "good" cut is within these $n$ cuts? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a graph with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges.

Let $\mathcal{D}$ be a pairwise independent distribution over $\{0,1\}^n$, and suppose that $x = (x_1,\ldots,x_n) \sim \mathcal{D}$. For every edge $(i,j)$, the probability that it is cut in the cut corresponding to $x$ is
$$
\Pr[x_i \neq x_j] = \frac{1}{2},
$$
due to pairwise independence. Therefore the *expected* number of edges cut is exactly $\frac{m}{2}$, by linearity of expectation. In particular, there is at least one realization of $x$ (that is, one point in the support of $\mathcal{D}$) which cuts at least $m/2$ edges.

Comment: Thanks. $\mathcal{D}$ is over $\{0,1\}^n$, which correspond to the algorithm that generates $n$ bits (and the de-randomized one loop over $2^n$ options). My Question is about the pseudo-random algorithm, which generate $\log n$ bits instead, and so loop over $n$ options. Why does it's support has a "good" cut, as well?

Comment: My answer is also about the pseudorandom distribution. The vector $x$ isn’t sampled uniformly. Rather, it is sample according to a pairwise uniform distribution $\mathcal D$.